# Check hash element present and return a value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

if I have an array of hashes like below(in JSON) and I want to check if an Id exists.

If the Id exists I then want to return the list of Currencies if they exist(may not in the case of Id 19).

How do I do this ?

"MyArray": [
        {
            "Id": 14,
            "Currencies": {
                "48": 840,
                "410": 840,
                "978": 826
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": 19
        }
    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a =  [ { "Id" => 14, "Currencies" => { "48" => 840, "410" => 840, "978" => 826 } }, { "Id" => 19 } ]
h = a.detect {|i| i["Id"] == 14 && i.has_key?("Currencies") }
h["Currencies"].values unless h.nil?
# => [840, 840, 826]
```

Comment: thanks Priti, will split out line 2 into 2 lines  because if you use Id of say 15 then accessing Currencies will fail as nil

Comment: @Noel that's why `h.values unless h.nil?` the line I wrote

Comment: change 14 to 15 to see what i mean

Comment: @Noel How much sweet it is .. :) glad to hear... :))